# Is pre-Brownian motion unique?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to understand the notion of pre-Brownian motion using the Book "Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus" by J. Le Gall.

He first define the Gaussian white noise to be some isometry $G$ from $L^2(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ to a centered Gaussian space, and also in page 12 he states that $G(1_A)$ is a Gaussian R.V. with $\mathcal{N}(0,\mu(A))$, for any Gaussian white noise $G$. Then in page 19, the pre-Brownian motion is defined as a random process $B_t$ such that $B_t=G(1_{[0,t]})$ for some $G$. But for any Gaussian white noise $G$, $G(1_{[0,t]})$ is always $\mathcal{N}(0,\mu(A))=\mathcal{N}(0,t)$, means that $B_t=\mathcal{N}(0,t)$ is uniquely defined.

I don't know if I missed anything.

Comment: What do you mean “is it unique”

Comment: I mean is $B_t$, a random process, always the same as the Gaussian process defined as $G_t=\mathcal{N}(0,t)$?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. It’s like asking if the real numbers are unique

Comment: Sorry I am bit missed up. Let's focus on the Gaussian white noise (GWN) first. A GWN is some isometry $G$ that mapping each function $f\in L^2(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ to a centered Gaussian random variable $G(f)$. Is it true any GWN (or any isometry $G$) will map $1_A$ to the Gaussian R.V. $N(0,\mu(A))$, i.e.,  $G(1_A)=N(0,\mu(A))$ for any GWN $G$? Or, for two GWN $G_1, G_2$, the image of $1_A$ under them are always the same, i.e., both equal to $N(0,\mu(A))$?

Comment: If $G$ is an isometry from $L^2$ to a centered gaussian space, then necessarily $G(1_A) =_d \mathcal N(0,\mu(A))$. On the other hand, $G_1(1_A) = G_2(1_A)$ depends on what you mean by equality

Comment: I seem to understand the problem here. $G_1(1_A)=G_2(1_A)$ is in the sense that the two image random variables have the same distribution. But two random variables that having the same distribution can be different, i.e., $P(X_1=X_2)\neq 1$. If so, then if we move to pre-Brownian motion (PBM), let's say we have two PBMs $B_t$ and $B'_t$. Is it true that $B_t$ and $B'_t$ always have the same distribution of $N(0,t)$, but $B_t$ and $B'_t$ can be different ($P(B_t'=B_t)\neq 1$).

Comment: Sounds right. Their distribution is the only thing that is unique. I would be very surprised if Le Gall claims anything else.